# 'Juggling Async' - Why does my solution not return anything at all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

After asking a question and getting a very helpful answer on what the 'Async Juggling' assignment in `learnyounode` was asking me to do, I set out to implement it myself.

The problem is, my setup isn't having any success!  Even though I've referred to other solutions out there, my setup simply isn't returning any results when I do a `learnyounode verify myscript.js`.

[GIST: jugglingAsync.js](https://gist.github.com/Asvarduil/569045ae96fc5aa57242)

```
var http = require('http');

var app = (function () {
    // Private variables...
    var responsesRemaining,
        urls = [],
        responses = [];

   var displayResponses = function() {
        for(var iterator in responses) {
            console.log(responses[iterator]);
        }
    };

    // Public scope...
    var pub = {};

    pub.main = function (args) {
        responsesRemaining = args.length - 2;

        // For every argument, push a URL and prep a response.
        for(var i = 2; i < args.length; i++) {
            urls.push(args[i]);
            responses.push('');
        }

        // For every URL, set off an async request.
        for(var iterator in urls) {
            var i = iterator;
            var url = urls[i];

            http.get(url, function(response) {
                response.setEncoding('utf8');

                response.on('data', function(data) {
                    if(response.headers.host == url)
                        responses[i] += data;
                });

                response.on('end', function() {
                    if(--responsesRemaining == 0)
                        displayResponses();
                });
            });
        }
    };

    return pub;
})();

app.main(process.argv);
```

**Question:** What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide relevant code in your post. Some people cannot or will not open external links. Furthermore, external links will eventually go down, rendering this question useless to other people.

Comment: @IngoBürk Provided code per request.  Thank you for reminding me  why that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
    for(var iterator in urls) {
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It actually loops over the properties of `urls` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Instead, you have to do something like

```
    for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        var url = urls[i];
        ...
    }
```

or

```
    urls.forEach(function(url, index) {
        ...
    });
```

Comment: I changed those `for(var iterator in collection) {}` loops to `collection.forEach(function (item[, index]) {})` instead.  My setup still isn't working, but thanks for helping me understand how JavaScript's `for(prop in object)` operators work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not properly looping through the arrays inside the `app` module, I was also not properly concatenating `data` returned from the `response.on('data')` event.  Originally I was doing...

```
responses[index] += data;
```

Instead, the correct thing to do was:

```
responses[index] = responses[index] + data;
```

Changing that, as well as the things noted by @arghbleargh got the 'Async Juggling' to fully verify!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested my code and it all worked:

```
~ $ node juggling_async.js site1 site2 site3 site4 ...
```

The JS code does not limit only to three sites.

```
var http = require('http');

// Process all the site-names from the arguments and store them in sites[].
// This way does not limit the count to only 3 sites.
var sites = [];
(function loadSites() {
    for(var i = 2, len = process.argv.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var site = process.argv[i];
        if(site.substr(0, 6) != 'http://') site = 'http://' + site;
        sites.push(site);
    }
})();

var home_pages = [];
var count = 0;
function httpGet(index) {
    var home_page = '';
    var site = sites[index];
    http.get(site, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            home_page += data;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            ++count;
            home_pages[index] = home_page;
            if(count == sites.length) {
                // Yahoo! We have reached the last one.
                for(var i = 0; i < sites.length; ++i) {
                    console.log('\n@@@@@@@@@@@@ Site #' + (+i+1) + ': ' + sites[i]);
                    console.log(home_pages[i]);
                    console.log('============================================\n');
                }
            }
        });
    })
    .on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Error at loop index ' + inddex + ': ' + e.message);
    })
    ;
}
for(var i = 0; i < sites.length; ++i) {
    httpGet(i);
}
```